# facing an undefined error while using ethers.utils.parseEther("1") in testing

Tags: javascript, node.js, solidity, hardhat

```js
let fundMe
   let mockV3Aggregator
   let deployer
   const sendValue = ethers.utils.parseEther("1")
beforeEach(async () => {
       // const accounts = await ethers.getSigners()
       // deployer = accounts[0]
       deployer = (await getNamedAccounts()).deployer
       await deployments.fixture(["all"])
       fundMe = await ethers.getContractAt("FundMe", deployer)
       mockV3Aggregator = await ethers.getContractAt(
           "MockV3Aggregator",
           deployer
       )
   }
```

the error message:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'utils')

also, I tried to feed the value directly to the sendValue variable and then this error pops up:

> TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'getContract')

PS: I have my utils folder populated with code below

```js
const { run } = require("hardhat")
async function verify(contractAddress, args) {
    console.log("Verifying contract..")
    try {
        await run("verify:verify", {
            // verify:verify the second verify is the subtask of thje actual verify task and {} is the object containing the actual parameters
            address: contractAddress,
            ConstructorArguments: args,
        })
    } catch (e) {} // to catch any errors
    if (e.message.toLowerCase().includes("already verified")) {
        console.log("Already Verified")
    } else {
        console.log(e)
    }
}
module.exports = { verify }
```

Answer (score 2):

In ethers 6 you can use:

`ethers.parseEther("")`

instead of `ethers.utils.parseEther()`

Answer (score 0):

"parseEther" function has been moved from ethers.utils to ethers.

Thus, to utilize that in version 6, simply use

```js
ethers.parseEther("")
```